# ViewController selected in a TabBar

Tags: tabbar, viewcontroller, selected

Is it possible to get the view controller selected in a TabBar? How can I do that? thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

someTabBarController.selectedViewController

A UITabBarController has a property named "selectedViewController".
Simply access it.